# Issue using filter AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, filter

I'm using $filter to iterate through an array and fetch a specific value

Below is my code:

```js
var selected = $filter('filter')($scope.folders, {url: el.selected[0] });
```

This code is working, but I got a problem when the url contain an accent and space like so :

/Users/Me/project/products/Poste à souder

In that case the string comparaison isn't working anymore.

What is the cleaner way to solve this situation ?

Comment: Can you show some code of your filter?

Comment: @Fidel90 this is my only code for the filter. My $scope.folders contain an Array of Json and el.selected[0] a string

Comment: Ah, you're talking about https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter, got it :)

Comment: try defining a custom comparator function to find if the problem is the string compare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's best to write your own filter:

```
app.filter("customFilter", function () {
    //the filter will accept an input array, the key you want to look for and the value that the key should have
    return function (array, key, value) {
      return array.filter(function(x){
        return (x.hasOwnProperty(key) && (x[key] === value));
      });
    };
});
```

And use it in your controller like:

```
$scope.filtered = $filter("customFilter")($scope.folders, "url", "/Users/Me/project/products/Poste à souder");
```

Check out a working demo [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/NmYvBH2XNC6Ve004kFBj?p=preview).

Comment: I just got a last tiny issue. When i Pass the third argument of your filter with my el.selected[0] which is a string it doesn't work. It's really weird cos if now I insert the third argument as you did with the value of el.selected[0] it works !

Comment: @musecz: Hmm...are you sure that your `el.selected[0]` holds the correct data? Where does its value come from?

Comment: el.selected is an array that I got when I click on a node from JS-Tree. in the el object I have a field like so :  selected: ["/Users/Me/project/products/Poste à souder"]. It's weird cos the value is correct and the type is string

Comment: @musecz: Like in this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/jQvtYoWIsNSjKRqtmZxt?p=preview ? You can add some additional code if necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks. In fact I noticed that the string are identical but not their length weirdly. el.selected[0] must had a white space or something else that we can't see when we console.log it !

Comment: Doing x[key].trim().length I got 127 and value.trim().length I got 128. I conclude it's not the whitespace

Comment: @musecz: Weird. It's difficult to solve this issue within the comments. Maybe it's better to open a new question regarding this topic.

Comment: I just Found that it breaks down my "à" in "a" and "`" in my el.selected[0] ... so it took 2 elements. I will open a new topic if I don't found how to resolve that.

Comment: new Topic Open : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885771/issue-with-nodejs-encoding

Answer (score 1):

That true. As a francophone, I've often encounter encoding/decoding issues with angularjs.

The source code of the default filter is as follow

```
function filterFilter()
{
    return function(array, expression, comparator)
    {
        if (!isArrayLike(array))
        {
            if (array == null)
            {
                return array;
            }
            else
            {
                throw minErr('filter')('notarray', 'Expected array but received: {0}', array);
            }
        }

        var expressionType = getTypeForFilter(expression);
        var predicateFn;
        var matchAgainstAnyProp;

        switch (expressionType)
        {
            case 'function':
                predicateFn = expression;
                break;
            case 'boolean':
            case 'null':
            case 'number':
            case 'string':
                matchAgainstAnyProp = true;
                //jshint -W086
            case 'object':
                //jshint +W086
                predicateFn = createPredicateFn(expression, comparator, matchAgainstAnyProp);
                break;
            default:
                return array;
        }

        return Array.prototype.filter.call(array, predicateFn);
    };
}
```

and the `predicate` generator stand as follow: it generate the default comparator if the provided one is not a function

```
function createPredicateFn(expression, comparator, matchAgainstAnyProp)
{
    var shouldMatchPrimitives = isObject(expression) && ('$' in expression);
    var predicateFn;

    if (comparator === true)
    {
        comparator = equals;
    }
    else if (!isFunction(comparator))
    {
        comparator = function(actual, expected)
        {
            if (isUndefined(actual))
            {
                // No substring matching against `undefined`
                return false;
            }
            if ((actual === null) || (expected === null))
            {
                // No substring matching against `null`; only match against `null`
                return actual === expected;
            }
            if (isObject(expected) || (isObject(actual) && !hasCustomToString(actual)))
            {
                // Should not compare primitives against objects, unless they have custom `toString` method
                return false;
            }

            actual = lowercase('' + actual);
            expected = lowercase('' + expected);
            return actual.indexOf(expected) !== -1;
        };
    }

    predicateFn = function(item)
    {
        if (shouldMatchPrimitives && !isObject(item))
        {
            return deepCompare(item, expression.$, comparator, false);
        }
        return deepCompare(item, expression, comparator, matchAgainstAnyProp);
    };

    return predicateFn;
}
```

---

Too much speech. You have the choice:

1. Provide a `comparator` to your filter [see the doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

   - but remember that you can't define inline function in angular template
   - you can define a function in that scope, but it will only be available in that scope
2. You can write your own filter

   ```
   .filter('myCustomFilter', function()
   {
       return function(input, criteria)
       {
           ... // your logic here
           return ...// the filtered values  
       };
   })
   ```