# Issue with nodeJS Encoding

Tags: node.js, encoding

So I'm confronted to a situation that I don't manage to resolve.

Here is my code :

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {

  showTree: function (req, res) {
    var _p;
    if (req.query.entity) {
      _p = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../uploads/Segmentation', req.query.entity);
    } else {
      _p = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../uploads/Segmentation', 'Default');
    }
    if (req.query.id == 1) {
      processReq(_p, res);
    } else {
      if (req.query.id) {
        _p = req.query.id;
        processReq(_p, res);
      } else {
        res.json(['No valid data found']);
      }
    }

    function processReq(_p, res) {
      var resp = [];
      var encoding = 'utf8';
      fs.readdir(_p,encoding, function(err, list) {
        if (typeof list !== 'undefined'){
          for (var i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            resp.push(processNode(_p, list[i]));
          }
          res.json(resp);
        } else {
          res.json(null);
        }
      });
    }

    function processNode(_p, f) {
      var s = fs.statSync(path.join(_p, f));
      return {
        "id": path.join(_p, f),
        "text": f,
        "icon" : s.isDirectory() ? 'jstree-custom-folder' : 'jstree-custom-file',
        "state": {
          "opened": false,
          "disabled": false,
          "selected": false
        },
        "li_attr": {
          "base": path.join(_p, f),
          "isLeaf": !s.isDirectory()
        },
        "children": s.isDirectory()
      };
    }
  }
};
```

The problem is with a repository called : "Poste à souder". If I console.log(list[i]) I obtain "Poste a` souder". 
How can I resolve this encoding issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify *encoding* option to `readdir()`:

```
var encoding = 'utf8'; // or the encoding you expect...
fs.readdir(_p, {encoding: encoding}, function(err, list) {
  ...
});
```

Please note that 'utf8' encoding is the default, so you're probably getting a different encoding...

See also the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback).

*Second note: server side (node.js) code here on SO code snippet does not work 'as-is'... :-)*

Comment: Thanks. Weirdly when I add the encoding in the second parameter I got this error thrown :  TypeError: callback must be a function

Comment: Yes, sorry, my mistake! Second parameter must be an object with an `encoding` property... Answer already updated...

Comment: Really strange... I did also notice that encoding can be a string *or* an object, so also the simpler form `fs.readdir(_p, encoding, function() {` should work... Are you sure parameter `_p` type is `String` or `Buffer`?

Comment: _p is a string. His value is a path, for instance : /Users/musecz/Lab/uploads/Segmentation/ccc. I construct his value using path.resolve

Comment: You should post all the relevant code, to help us... *P.S.: don't forget to accept answer, if it helps you...*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110379/discussion-between-marcos-and-musecz).

Comment: I upload the complete code. I use it to build a Tree of my repository